How can I make the curves react to the texture's values?
I want to change the color of a curve based on a noise texture. I created the curves using Geometry Nodes and added a Store Named Attribute node so I can use it in the Shading tab. However, when I try to use the Fac of the Noise Texture as the value, nothing happens. How can I change the color of the curve based on the noise texture?
Geometry Nodes:

Shading Tab:


You try to store the data in a Store Named Attribute set to Instance, but after a Realize Instances node. There are no instances to store the attribute then.
And if you want your Mix Shader node to take the Noise Texture values as factor which are used for offsetting the curve points on the Z axis, then you should store the attribute data on those points by setting the Store Named Attribute to Points:

Something similar in the Shader Editor, since the attribute data is not stored on instances, you do not get any values when you choose Instancer in the Attribute node, you have to switch it to Type: Geometry. I also added a Color Ramp for more contrast, since the actual values are not differing very much from 0.5 neither up nor down so the effect was not very visible in the material:

I would suggest to use a Color Ramp but set to Constant anyway, because you are mixing non-metallic and metallic, and in reality something is either metallic or not, so a smooth transition between those materials would not really make sense.
By the way, you can use the attribute for manipulating all the values in a Principled BSDF, you do not have to make two different ones and combine them with a Mix Shader. Although of course it could be easier to have them separate to see how they are set up.

